# Matlab setting default font

Tags: matlab

First of all I am creating a very basic graphics package, similar to paint.

I have a global variable for font size which is created using:

```
global font
font=uisetfont;
```

And at the beginning of my program I am creating default values for my variables as shown here:

```
%STARTUP CODE
function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);
global strokecolour strokewidth fillcolour font
fillcolour = 'white';
strokecolour = 'black';
strokewidth = 1;
font = Arial,normal,normal,points,12;        <--- this part (I know it's wrong)
```

However I can't seem to get the syntax for the font properties correct, I had a look online and couldn't find anything, even asking the command window for the properties brings up this:

```
>> uisetfont

ans = 

      FontName: 'Arial'
    FontWeight: 'normal'
     FontAngle: 'normal'
     FontUnits: 'points'
      FontSize: 10
```

Which again, I can't seem to get to work...

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to manually set your `font` variable to a set of data as if you had instead called `uisetfont`? (Even then it's not clear what happens next as your code ends.) The output of `uisetfont` is a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) as is stated in the documentation. Have you tried using a structure?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to set it to a set of data, as if `uisetfont` had been used without the user doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling this

```
font = uisetfont;
```

brings up a window that when closed sets the variable `font` to a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) containing several fields (use `whos` or `class(font)` to determine this). You can replicate this in one line with parameter-value notation:

```
font = struct('FontName','Arial','FontWeight','normal','FontAngle','normal','FontUnits','Points','FontSize',10)
```

Or you can use '.' notation to set each field:

```
font.FontName = 'Arial';
font.FontWeight = 'normal';
font.FontAngle = 'normal';
font.FontUnits = 'points';
font.FontSize = 10;
```

This same '.' notation is useful getting the the field out of the structure as well.